# How to load dynamic dropown data using the formArray index on selection

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formarray

I have a scenario like add/remove form group with multiple form controls.

For instance,

[image]

The First dropdown is country list and second dropdown is states list based on the selected country and the last input control is comments.

the issue is, when I load the page country dropdown data loads country api by default but the states are not loading properly based on selected country. When I change the country, all other country states dropdown also changed similarly.

For instance,

[image]

Here my try
**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]='formName'>
              <div formArrayName="controllerArray" class="ui-g ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " >
                <div  class="ui-g  ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " *ngFor="let item of formName.controls.controllerArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">  
                  <div class="ui-md-4">                   
                    <label class="mandatory"
                  >{{ labels["STATE_OF_INCORPORATION_FILE_NUMBER"] }}
                  <span class="colon"></span>
                </label>           

                <select formControlName="select1" class="ui-inputtext" [(ngModel)]="item.controls.select1.value" (change)="changeAction($event,i)"> 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let c of countryOptions" [value]="c.value">{{c.label}}</option>
                 
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-4">
                <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
                <select formControlName="select2" class="ui-inputtext" [(ngModel)]="item.controls.select2.value"> 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let b of businessStateOptions" [value]="b.value">{{b.label}}</option>
                 
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-3">
                <label class="lbl-hidden"> comments  </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  pInputText
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="input"    
                />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-md-1">
                  <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
                  <br/>
                  <button (click)='removeInput(i)'  style="min-width: auto;"  pButton icon="fa fa-minus"></button>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            
            <button class="add-remove-btn" pButton (click)='addInput()' icon="fa fa-plus"></button>`
```

**Angular8 TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'
import { FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';

export class EntityEditComponent implements OnInit {
public countryOptions = [];

formName =this.fb.group({
    controllerArray: this.fb.array([])
  })  

ngOnInit() {    
 this.countryOptions = [{"label":"United States","value":"US"},{"label":"Canada","value":"CA"}]
}

 changeAction(e, index) { 
  if(index == 1 ) {     // Here I'm trying to change the data if country is selected CA
 let businessStateOptions = []
businessStateOptions= [{label:"Alberta",value:"CA"}]

const controlArray = <FormArray> this.formName.get('controllerArray');
    controlArray.controls[index].get('select2').setValue( businessStateOptions);
    }  
}



addInput() {(this.formName.get('controllerArray') as FormArray).push(this.fb.group({select1:'', select2:'',input:''})) }

removeInput(index) { this.formName.controls.controllerArray["controls"].splice(index,1) }

}
```

**Expected results are,**

When I change the country, selected country states needs to be loaded in the states dropdown without effecting any other dropdowns.

Comment: Come on buddy did it work?

Comment: Nope, It is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You're kinda getting yourself into a pickle with your approach. You're mixing reactive forms with template driven forms. You firstly need to remove anything with `ngModel`. Then remove your `changeAction` method. Then change `[value]` to `[ngValue]`. Then in your `select2` dropdown change the way you are recalling the relevant states based on that `item` country value. Something like this:

```
<form [formGroup]='formName'>
              <div formArrayName="controllerArray" class="ui-g ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " >
                <div  class="ui-g  ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad " *ngFor="let item of formName.controls.controllerArray.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">  
                  <div class="ui-md-4">                   
                    <label class="mandatory"
                  >{{ labels["STATE_OF_INCORPORATION_FILE_NUMBER"] }}
                  <span class="colon"></span>
                </label>           

                <select formControlName="select1" class="ui-inputtext"> 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let c of countryOptions" [ngValue]="c.value">{{c.label}}</option>
                 
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-4">
                <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
                <select formControlName="select2" class="ui-inputtext"> 
                  <option>--Select--</option>
                  <option *ngFor="let b of getRelevantStates(item.controls.select1.value)" [ngValue]="b.value">{{b.label}}</option>
                 
                </select>
              </div>
              <div class="ui-md-3">
                <label class="lbl-hidden"> comments  </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  pInputText
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="input" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-md-1">
                  <label class="lbl-hidden"> State </label>
                  <br/>
                  <button (click)='removeInput(i)'  style="min-width: auto;"  pButton icon="fa fa-minus"></button>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            
            <button class="add-remove-btn" pButton (click)='addInput()' icon="fa fa-plus"></button>
```

You'll also need to make a new method to recall the relevant states based on this item in your form array:

```
    getRelevantStates(countryId){
var states = [];
    // Return states based on countryId.
return states;
    }
```

**@Andrew:**
As per the above logic, getRelevantStates() keeps calling, eventually respective states data would not be loaded.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your expertise solution. But the issue here is, getRelevantStates() method keeps calling the states API's since it is in loop *ngFor. We can not bind data eventually.  I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: Ah I thought you already had the states data on hand without requiring an api lookup. The next best thing to do is to create a states form array. And then after you have changed select1 you do your states api call and insert it into your formarray. This states formarray would be a sibling property of select1 and select2.